# What does the 'split' in this scope accomplish?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found this scope on a blog post...

```
scope :search_by_title, -> (title) { where("(title like ?) OR title in (?)", "%#{title}%", title.split) }
```

... and I'm trying to figure out the second half of the OR pair.

If the query was "banana cake",
it seems to me like the scope would work like this

```
scope :search_by_title, -> ("banana cake") { where("(title like ?) OR title in (?)", "%banana cake%", ["banana","cake"]) }
```

and this doesn't seem useful at all.

Anyone got an example that demonstrates how this scope would work?

Thanks

Comment: When you write `title in (?)` and pass a array to them; you are especifiying to SQL compiler title must have a exactly value of one of this array's element.

Comment: Guess I'll have to crank up a rails app and check this out. I always thought I could accomplish the same thing just using 'title like'.

Answer (score 2):

- The first part of the scope (before `OR`) will work when your title includes "`banana cake`".
- The second part of the scope (after `OR`) will work when your query is either "`banana`" or "`cake`".
- So, it is useful because you can search for either "`banana cake`" or "`banana`" or "`cake`".
- If you don't have that `title.split` part in there, then your search for either "`banana`" or "`cake`" would not work. It will only for "`banana cake`".

Comment: I probably wrote my question wrong. But it seems like I could type 'cake' and it would match 'banana cake' without using the SQL 'in' portion of the query. See why I say this here... https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/lkj2dewi3ofvkgc/8v0bqx6w.jpg